# Looking for a PC 2D platformer game from the mid-2000s or earlier

Tags: gaming, identify-this-game

I'm trying to find the name of a PC game I used to play as a kid in the early/mid-2000s. All I remember from it is that it was a 2D platformer and that one of the levels looked like the following image:

[image]

I distinctly remember having to jump over those deadly purple vines. I think you could collect a gun to shoot at enemies. There *may* have been something like a spider in the level that you had to kill. I also vaguely recall poison/lava tiles on another level? Sorry for the vagueness!

Comment: I can't believe the sketch resulted in an actual answer. I was going to flag it as off-topic...

Answer (score 74, accepted):

That sounds exactly like my memory of [Dangerous Dave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangerous_Dave).  A playable version is hosted on the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/msdos_DDAVEVGA_shareware).

[image: Dangerous Dave Screenshot]